# TryGetInt32 throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: json.net, system.text.json

Call me crazy, but I was under the impression that there was a convention of `try` which meant give it a go, but if you can't then get back to me and let me know that it was a "no-go".

I have recently started a new project and I have decided to use `System.Text.Json` instead of `Newtonsoft` since it has been out for a while now and I like to play with new things.

I have the following bit of code in a `JsonConverter`:

```
using (var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
{
    if (jsonDoc.RootElement.TryGetInt32(out int number))
    {
    }
}
```

When it is a number, it works awesomely, but when it is anything but a number, it throws as if I was calling `GetInt32()`.

In the custom converter, I sometimes get a number back, but I also can get an object back which contains the number that I am expecting as well as a string. I thought that I would be able to test for this using the `TryGetInt32` method.

I have two questions:

1. How could I test if I am getting the number back, or getting the number AND the string?, and
2. What is the difference between `TryGetInt32(out int number)` and `GetInt32()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TryGetInt32 throws exception if the value is not a number type.

It does not throw and returns false if the value is a number type but not a number kind convertible to int32.

I hope the following additional check helps:

```
using (var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
{
    if(jsonDoc.RootElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number &&
       jsonDoc.RootElement.TryGetInt32(out int number))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first question :
using int.TryParse(variable,result) : this return bool and store variable if integer in result
example:

```
 string json = "5";
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(json, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

second question:
TryGetInt32(Int32) :Attempts to represent the current JSON number as an Int32 and return bool .
Getint32(): get specific value as int32 in this case you must be sure that the value is integer

Comment: When I use TryGetInt32, it throws rather than returning false, which is what I would expect from GetInt32.